# prepareForSegue not getting called when registering a custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

This isn't a problem of the segue identifier being mis-spelled or anything like that. The method `prepareForSegue` isn't actualy getting called when I tap on a cell in a tableViewController. The log statement before the control statement isn't logging if I tap on the cell, only when I add a new cell.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"prepare for segue"); //not getting logged if I tap on an existing cell
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"AddTopic"]) {
        //
        works fine to add a new cell
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"]){
        NSLog(@"in segue to display edit");

        MMDisplayEditViewController *devc = (MMDisplayEditViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
```

You can see in the image below that there is a push segue set up from the cell in table view controller to the display edit view controller. [image]

Why might `prepareForSegue` not get called?

Note, I am using a custom class for the table view cell, but I don't see why that would influence anything.

Update

I registered the custom cell in viewDidLoad of the main table view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     [self.tableView registerClass:[MMTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Comment: are you creating static cell in storyboard , or reusing a cell ?

Comment: @pawan it's a dynamic cell, reusing a cell called "Cell"

Comment: in that case @KerrM solution should work.

Comment: The answer you accepted is a workaround, not an answer to your question. The setup you say you have should result in prepareForSegue being called, so there must be something else going on. How do you have the "Add Topic" segue connected? Does the segue to the next controller execute properly even though prepareForSegue isn't called?

Comment: @rdelmar the segue for addTopic works perfectly i.e. prepareForSegue gets called when I click on the button to add a new topic. It's only when I tap on an existing cell that prepareForSegue doesnt' get called? to setup the addTopic segue, I did control drag from the + button to the add topic view controller

Comment: And does the segue itself work when you click on the cell -- does it go to the detail view controller?

Comment: @rdelmar now that I added the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath, when I click on a cell, it goes to the detail view controller. Note, the addtopicViewcontroller is a completely separate view controller in story board

Comment: @rdelmar fyi, I am using a custom cell class for this project but I don't see why that would make a difference since prepareForSegue is a tableViewController method

Comment: Ok, that still doesn't answer my question. Before you added the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, did the segue work? Did it go to the detail view controller when you touched a cell?

Comment: @rdelmar sorry, misunderstood. No, the segue didn't work, it didn't go to the detail view controller. That's the whole point of the question. However, the add topic segue did work (to the add topic view controller)

Comment: If you control-click on the cell in the storyboard, under the section "Triggered Segues" does it have an entry that says "selection" on the left side and "push" (with the name of the controller underneath push) on the right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53981/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-brainlikeadullpencil).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by registering the class of the cell in viewDidLoad,

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[MMTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

You setup the segue from a cell in the storyboard, but by registering your class, the table view gets its cell from the class definition, not from the one in the storyboard that has the segue attached to it. To fix the problem, just delete that line.

The documentation for this is somewhat incomplete. You should only register the class if the cell is made completely in code. The fact that you're using a custom cell, doesn't change this fact -- if you have a cell in the storyboard, and you set it to a custom class, you shouldn't register anything.

Comment: Then what should I do if I want to layout the cell in custom nib?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of linking your segue from the cell to the next view controller, link from the view controller to the next view controller. Give that segue an identifier and implement the delegate method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: I have one other table view based application that I made and I didn't have to implement that method like that

Answer (score -1):

you are add this name "ShowDetail" in the segue in the storyboard if yes 
use this code in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"societe" sender:indexPath];
```