# ios7 Storybaoard UITableViewCell not applying to table

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I am adding a custom UITableViewCell to a UITableView in storyboard - via the prototype cell and a class file. When run, the row height is correct, but the content is still using the default with cell.textLabel.text, not my [cell.horseName setText:@"string"] setting.From reading the other posts on StackOverflow I've added:

RankingsTableViewController.m:viewDidLoad:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[RankingTableViewCell class]
       forCellReuseIdentifier:@"raceRankingCell"];
```

And also tried replacing:

```
RankingTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

with:

```
RankingTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[RankingTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

With no effect.

Here is what the storyboard looks like for the table:
[image]

From the tree view, you can see the Cell Identifier is `raceRankingCell`, in the Connections inspector, they are all hooked up to the class file:

Code:

RankingTableViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RankingTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *raceLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *horseNameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *jockeyLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *rankingLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *programIdLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *horseImage;

@end
```

RankingTableViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"raceRankingCell";

    RankingTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    /* Test#1- no change in behavior 
    RankingTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[RankingTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
     */

    // Any data yet? If not, show the no data yet cell
    if([_raceResultsArray count] < 1) {
        DLog(@"No race results yet");
        [cell.horseNameLabel setText:@"Data is loading... - horseName"];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Data is loading... - textLabel";
```

When I use the line `cell.textLabel.text = @"Data is loading... - textLabel";` the string is displayed.

What am I missing?

Comment: You shouldn't register the class if you make the cell in the storyboard. See my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741278/prepareforsegue-not-getting-called-when-registering-a-custom-cell/23745762#23745762

Comment: @rdelmar Set this up was an answer. Looks like that fixed the problem. I only added the line when it was failing and I looked up the crash error (raceRankingCell needs to be registered...) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a cell is defined in a storyboard, you shouldn't register the class. Registering a class means the table view will get the cell (including all its subviews) from the class implementation, so it should only be used when you've defined the cell wholly in code (no xib or storyboard). Deleting that line should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
RankingTableViewCell *cell = (RankingTableViewCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: Tried this also, see comment // Test#1. I did not try the casting... I'll try that. Thank you.